# How to solve a Sitemap error: Submitted Sitemap Under Folder

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have submitted a sitemap that is under a folder of root domain.
Example: `https://www.example.com/sitemap_in/sitemap.xml`

And now it is showing me **error** in GSC. Showing me status **"Couldn't Fetch"**

I checked the submitted sitemap in different sitemap validator tool and it's shown me error:

> Incorrect HTTP header content-type: "text/html" (expected: "application/xml")

My website is built on **React JS**

Comment: Can you post part of your sitemap here, you can disguise your domain by using example.com

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing, the problem is not in that it's on a folder, but that the **MIME type** that your web server responds is not of type **"application/xml"**.

Depending on your web server being **IIS**, **Apache** or other, you have to configure the extension XML to the correct Mime Type.